# How to calculate sum of hour between records based on column value

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a table `"services"` which has two columns `up(boolean type)` and `readingTime(DateTime type)`. Now I want to calculate total number of hours the up column value is TRUE. what is the best way to do it in Rails/ Mysql

Comment: Do you mean you want to get the hours from the datatime column or total the hours over many rows. _Your question is very unclear_

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes I want to get the total hours over many row. The idea is to display total number of hours the service is running.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [`TIMESTAMPDIFF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff)

```
SELECT *, TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, readingTime, now()) AS hours
FROM services
WHERE up = true;
```

**EDIT**

If you want total hours for given date range pass the dates instead

```
SELECT *, TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, readingTime, now()) AS hours
FROM services
WHERE up = true
AND (reading_on BETWEEN startDate AND endDate;
```

Comment: is there any way to get the total hours for given date range, for example i want to get the uptime between two give dates. Something like below

SELECT COUNT(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, reading_on, '2016-09-02 23:59:59') AS hours) FROM `services`  WHERE (reading_on between '2016-09-02 00:00:00' AND '2016-09-02 23:59:59' AND  uptime=true);

Comment: This query doesnt work, i have uptime value true & false  on alternative rows, but this query returns same result. FYI I want to sum the service total running time.